# How can I install and configure java for jruby on OS X?

Tags: macos, jruby

What versions of Java can jruby work on?

Is there an advantage to having one version or the other?

How can I install and configure the best version on OS X?

Answer (score 1):

JRuby currently (in the 1.7.x versions) runs on Java 6 and up. Java 7 introduced a new bytecode primitive, `invokedynamic`, which has the potential of speeding up dynamic languages including JRuby; but [as of JRuby 1.7.5, this is disabled under Java 7](http://jruby.org/2013/10/07/jruby-1-7-5) because of some unresolved issues. It's expected to be reenabled when Java 8 is released around March 2014, although you can turn it on now if you really want to try it, using the `jruby.compile.invokedynamic=true` property; or you can use a beta version of OpenJDK 8). See [this page on performance tuning](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/PerformanceTuning) for a little more information.

Comment: okay -- how do i install a new jvm version on os x, and do i need to tell jruby to use it?